# Retrieving Values from Constantly Update File

Tags: power-automate

How can I retrieve the most up-to-date data from a continuously modified Excel file (xlsx) stored in SharePoint, using a manually triggered flow for testing purpose first? Currently, I am using the "List rows present in a table" action to obtain the initial data successfully. However, when the file gets updated, this action fails with an error stating that the table has been removed or cannot be found. Is there a method to obtain the latest data from the constantly modified xlsx file.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the flow with the resulting error?

Comment: @Skin Hi, I actually solved this problem by using Get tables in the flow. The reason my table cannot be found was everytime when the file get updated, the ID of the table had been changed. Thank you for the response!